# SSIS derived column expression for date difference

Tags: ssis

I have an column in my source table as `[Valyyyymmdd] [nvarchar](24) NULL`:

```
Valyyyymmdd 
=================
20130503
20120403
00000000
20110523
20100715
```

I want to get the difference with `getdate()`, so I used the below query in my source

```
 DATEDIFF(DAY, IIF( [Valyyyymmdd] = '00000000', CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112),     [Valyyyymmdd]) , getdate()) as SalesStageAging
```

but I need to get the `Valyyyymmdd` and do ssis derived column to get the difference in date resulting in `int` value.

Kindly provide me the expression which has to be written in derived column expression

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DATEDIFF("d",[Valyyyymmdd] == "00000000" ? GETDATE() : (DT_DBDATE)(SUBSTRING([Valyyyymmdd],1,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING([Valyyyymmdd],5,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([Valyyyymmdd],7,2)),GETDATE())
```

Assuming `[Valyyyymmdd]` is a string in the format "yyyyMMdd", we split it into the year, month and date parts, insert hyphens between parts to format it as "yyyy-MM-dd" and then cast it as a date i.e. datatype `DT_DBDATE`. Finally, we use the conditional operator to check if value equals "00000000", and compare either current date, or the date parsed from input with current date to return the result.

Comment: [Valyyyymmdd] [nvarchar](24) NULL

Comment: Here , the expression is showing red when i applied in the derived column expression.. 

Could you let me know the other way of writing the expression

Comment: What error message do you get? Also, are you storing this as date and time both? If so, you can do something similar to get string in datetime format and use the `DT_DBTIMESTAMP` for casting.

Comment: In table, if the column is having 20140810  ;

i need the result to be 10 returning in the expression.

I Tryed..
DATEDIFF(DAY, CONVERT(DATE,(CASE WHEN [Valyyyymmdd] = '00000000' THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),112) ELSE [Valyyyymmdd] END),112), GETDATE()) AS SalesStageAging

this is also not working